# Verification with IValidatableObject

Tags: c#, validation, linq-to-entities

I applied the `IValidatableObject` interface to the student class coming from the database. However, I do not know how to do this verification on the `Form1` side. How can I verify the student class in `Form1` and show the error messages to the user?

```
public partial class students:IValidatableObject
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public short StudentMemberNum { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string StudentSurname { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StudentBirthDate { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StudentName))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("The student's name is required.", new string[] { "StudentName" });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's going to be hard to help without the code from Form1 as well - where you are calling `Validate`

Comment: Hello there
Form protection Validator. I found the solution with the TryValidateObject () class. Is such a use right, I wonder?

db.students.Add(student);
            var Context = new ValidationContext(student);
            List<ValidationResult> ErrorList= new List<ValidationResult>();
            bool Error= Validator.TryValidateObject(student, Context, HataListesi, true);
            foreach (ValidationResult validate in ErrorList)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(validate.ErrorMessage);
            }